# Can't find path todolist_app / index.html Hey, does anyone know ? #TemplateDoesNotExist

Tags: django, os.path

I have updated django, pip and python to the latest version. I created the .html files inside the templates folder. I have defined the path to the folder in Setting, but it is not accessible.

> 

```
TemplateDoesNotExist error on server. TemplateDoesNotExist at 
/todolist_app/index.html Request Method: GET Request

URL:http://127.0.0.1:8000/ Django Version: 3.1.7 Exception Type:
TemplateDoesNotExist Exception Value: todolist_app/index.html

 Exception Location:C:\Users\kuudere\anaconda3\lib\site- packages\django\template\loader.py,line 19, in get_template 

Python Executable:C:\Users\kuudere\anaconda3\python.exe Python Version: 
django:django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:
 C:\Users\kuudere\Desktop\todolist\todolist\templates\todolist_app\todolist_app\index.html(Source does not exist) django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
C:\Users\kuudere\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\todolist_app\index.html(Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
C:\Users\kuudere\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\templates\todolist_app\index.html(Source does not exist)
```

---

Django version 3.1 is installed and cannot find the path to index.html.
I added the extension. `INSTALLED_APPS` `= I have added an app.
But I'm not sure about that;

```
'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates / todolist_app']
```

Did I make a false here?

```
    TEMPLATES = [{
                
            'BACKEND':'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        
            'DIRS': [BASE_DIR /'templates/todolist_app'],
            'APP_DIRS': True,
            'OPTIONS': {
                'context_processors': [
                    'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                    'django.template.context_processors.request',
                    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                ],
            },
        },
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

for starters it isn't the best to add sub directory of templates into base dir.

Error might be due to a wrong path. Check the view and change it to the right path.